# Socket not receiving the complete stream

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm coding a program to send and another to receive a stream of images by sockets.  In general terms:

- On the client's side: I get the image and pre-visualize it in the client side. Then I sent it through a socket.
- On the server's side: I wait for the image, and then pre-visualize it.

Here are the snippets of code related to socket:

**EDITED:**

**Client's Side**

```
unsigned int bytes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += bytes) {
    if ((bytes = send(clientSocket->getSocketDescriptor(), (char*)inputImage.data + i, imgSize - i, 0)) == 0) {
        assert(false);
    }
    std::cout << "Sent: " << bytes << std::endl;
}
char notifyChar[1];
recv(clientSocket->getSocketDescriptor(), notifyChar , 1 , 0);
```

**Server's Side**

```
unsigned int bytes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += bytes) {
    if ((bytes = recv(serverQuads.getSocketDescriptor(0), (char *)sockData + i, imgSize - i, 0)) == -1) {
        assert(false);
    }
    std::cout << " Received: " << bytes << std::endl;
}       

char notifyChar[1] = { '0' };
send(serverQuads.getSocketDescriptor(0),notifyChar , 1, 0);
```

The image size is 57600 (`imgSize` is calculated from 3 const (`WIDTH`, `HEIGHT` and `CHANNELS`)), and `send()` returns that value. But the server only receive 53504 bytes, so it returns to `recv()` but nothing happens. It keeps waiting for the other 4096 bytes endless.

I'm a bit confused now. I read many post but can't find out the trouble. Can anybody help me?

**SOLVED:**

The error was out of this snippets. Another thread was reading from the socketDescriptor and waiting for exactly 4096 bytes. So, now everything it's fine.

Comment: First of all you have to remember that TCP is a *streaming* protocol, it doesn't really have "packets", it's all just a stream of data, which means that if you send two "packets" they may be received as one on the other end. Also, are you sure that the packet sizes are equal on both ends? Print out `PACKET_SIZE` on both ends.

Comment: Which protocol are you using TCP or UDP?
And why not use a library for stuff like that?

Comment: TCP or UDP?  Why are you printing "Received: 2400 bytes" even when `bytes != 2400` ?

Comment: Also note that unless the image size is a multiple of `PACKET_SIZE`, you're not sending the complete image.

Comment: I use TCP socket. Firstly I tried sending the whole buffer of the image. But then i receive partialy the buffer and recv blocks the server's app. I use that packet size because the image is 120*160*3, so its divisible

Comment: Based on your comments I'm gonna make some fixes. Thanks you.

Comment: It is normal for recv to get only a partial buffer. You must pay attention to the recv returned value, and keep calling recv until you have a complete picture. You might also get a complete picture plus a part of the next one. Your code is responsible for putting the partials back together properly.

Comment: I made some changes. Now the server check the size of received stream and wait for the rest. But, in spite of sending all bytes, the server only receive them partially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the return value of `recv` to find out how many bytes were received. TCP delivers you a boundaryless stream of data. It is not message based.

This means you can receive parts of a message or multiple messages in one read call. Your code *must* be able to deal with that.

Comment: Now I'm using the returned value of recv, but keep receiving less bytes than sended.

Comment: You are using the variable bytes which is uninitialized. This is undefined behavior. Fix that.

Comment: I've just fix it, but the trouble is the same. Fortunately `bytes`was not used before assigning it a value.

Comment: Code looks good. Something else is going on. Maybe, you have been reading 4096 bytes from the same socket before trying to read the image. You could have accidentally discarded data. 4096 is a suspicious value. Sounds like the size of a buffer of yours.

Comment: Yes it's very suspicious that size... I think that it's never used previously, but I'm going to investigate it. I'll comment you as soon as I get some results. Thanks you

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!! It's solved. The trouble was outside that code... I get the socket descriptor from other class that manage the connections and has a individual thread that reads from the socket and... Exactly it was reading 4096 bytes. So everything if fine now. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the third parameter of recv() both on windows and on linux is the size of char[] buffer, not the size received. it's used in order to prevent segmentation fault error.

Comment: I think that it's now solved with the new snippet of code. But keep receiving less bytes than sended

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following

- When you are sending the packets from the client introduce delay of a few seconds ( this is only for debugging ) between individual packet transmission. Then check on the server side if you are receiving individual packets.
  If tcpdump is enabled run the following command on the client:

  tcpdump -nnv -s0 -ieth0 dst host dsthostip and tcp

and the following command on the server

```
tcpdump -nnv -s0 -ieth0 src host srchostip and tcp
```

Check the output of these commands to ensure that the correct size packets are being transmitted and received and if not then which side is the culprit.

- Check the size of socket buffers. Socket buffers have a default size ( 64KB is the default I believe) and if the data arrives too fast, the socket buffer may overflow and packets may get lost though this should be an unlikely scenario if a TCP socket is used. You can increase the size of the buffers and check if problem persists.
- Run netstat -s command on the server side and check under IP and TCP label to see if any packets are getting lost or dropped.
  Hope this helps.